# Why does ternary operator work and others don't in React JSX

Tags: reactjs

```
return (
        <li className="blog-page__item"
            key={i}>
            {(itemName === 'Small') ? <Smallitem data={item}/> : null}
            {(itemName === 'Middle')  ? <MiddleItem data={item}/> : null}
            {(itemName === 'Big')    ? <BigItem data={item}/> : null}
        </li>
      )
```

Why does this code work but if I use **if** or **switch** statements it doens't?

Comment: JSX doesn't "work" with statements. Stuff inside `{}` blocks are evaluated as expressions, such as a ternary expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [DOCS](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just
>   syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction. Take this
>   basic example:
>
> ```
>  // This JSX: ReactDOM.render(<div id="msg">Hello World!</div>,
>  mountNode);
>
>
>
> // Is transformed to this JS:
> ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div", {id:"msg"}, "HelloWorld!"), mountNode); This means that if statements don't fit in. Take
> ```
>
> this example:
>
> ```
> // This JSX: <div id={if (condition) { 'msg' }}>Hello World!</div>
>
> // Is transformed to this JS: React.createElement("div", {id: if(condition) { 'msg' }}, "Hello World!");
> ```
>
> That's not valid JS. You
>       probably want to make use of a ternary expression:
>
> ```
> ReactDOM.render(<div id={condition ? 'msg' : null}>Hello World!</div>,
> mountNode);
> ```